# How to filter data with dynamic created checkboxs in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have created a list of checkbox and I want that when I click on one or more checkbox the result should get filtered based on the checkbox checked.
Can any one help me how I can archive this. I an using Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply logic as below, may be you have to modify something.

```
public selectedItems: any = [];
```

After Assign Datasource to checkbox: (add IsSelected field, so we can apply filter on data when required)

```
this.dataSource.forEach((row: any) => {
    row.IsSelected = false;
});
```

CkeckBox Click Event:

```
public OnCheckBoxClicked(value: any): any {
    this.selectedItems = [];       
    setTimeout(() => {
        let selectedRows = this.dataSource.filter((row: any) => row.IsSelected == true);
        if (selectedRows != null && selectedRows.length > 0) {
            this.selectedItems = selectedRows;                
        }
        console.log(this.selectedItems);
    }, 300);
}
```